# cannot follow the python git tutorials

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I have lately installed python-git package, and when trying to follow the tutorials over at the following link, I find that certain methods are missing...

http://packages.python.org/GitPython/0.3.2/tutorial.html#tutorial-label

Here is what came out of my interpreter:

```
>>> from git import *
>>> repo = Repo.init('/home/deostroll/scripts/synchost')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Repo' has no attribute 'init'
>>> repo = Repo('/home/deostroll/scripts/synchost')
>>> repo.is_dirty()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
>>>
```

Comment: am I looking at an outdated version of the tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those commands work for me, so I agree with the other answer that you're probably using an outdated version.  If you're on linux and have [PIP](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/), installed, on the command line you can do:

```
pip install --upgrade GitPython
```

to upgrade to the latest version.  (Sidenote: for me on Fedora, the command is actually pip-python, so it depends on your distro).

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely that you're using a very outdated verison of `GitPython`. In version 0.3, [`is_dirty`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/0.3/git/repo/base.py#L486) is a method, and [`init`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/0.3/git/repo/base.py#L636) exists.

In version 0.1, `is_dirty` is a [property](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/0.1/lib/git/repo.py#L483), and [`init_bare`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/0.1/lib/git/repo.py#L302) is defined, but not `init`.

Comment: I got this from the ubuntu software centre...and yes the version is outdated!